# What does "-1" and "x2" mean in a triangle symbol on a schematic?

Tags: operational-amplifier, inverter, symbol

In [this document](https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/www/doc/application-note/an551.pdf), P. 5, "test circuit 1", there are triangle symbols with "-1" inside, and another one with "x2" inside. What do they mean?

[image: triangles]

Comment: I'd guess they mean op-amps connected as inverters (-1) or as amplifiers of gain 2 (x2).

Comment: Why could you not guess what they mean?  They are amplifiers right? not logic.

Comment: Yes, I suspected that, but was not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are generic gain blocks. They multiply the input signal by the factor shown inside the triangle. So, a -1 inverts the signal while a x2 doubles the amplitude of the signal.

Comment: thx Eliot. It's interesting that this answer got 5 votes, while the question itself got no vote at all. If someone appreciates an answer, why does he not appreciate the corresponding question?